# How to limit current scope of nested form to first item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a simple discussion board in Rails. Every new `Topic` creates also a first `Reply` that includes the content. This is my current schema.

```
Topic
> title:string
> user_id: integer
has_many :replies
accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies

Reply
> topic_id: integer
> user_id: integer 
> content: text
belongs_to :topic
```

The current `topics/_form.html.haml` is something like this

```
= form_for @topic fo |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.fields_for :replies 
    = reply.text_area :content
```

The problem is when trying to edit a Topic, I see all the list of replies as editable since it's iterating the `fields_for  :replies` field in the form partial. I should only see the first one.

What would be a convenient way to limit this iteration to its current first available reply only while also building a new one if a topic is new?

I ended up with something like this that works but I guess there should be a better way.

```
# Topic model
has_one :owner_reply, class_name: 'Reply'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner_reply

# Form partial view
= form_for @topic fo |f|
  - reply_resource = (@topic.new_record? ? :replies : :owner_reply)
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.fields_for :replies 
    = reply.text_area :content
```

These are the full `TopicsController#create` and `update` actions.

```
  def create
    @board = Board.find(params[:board_id])
    @topic = @board.topics.new(topic_params)
    @topic.user_id = current_user.id
    @topic.replies.each { |reply| reply.user_id = current_user.id }
    if @topic.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to topic_path(@topic) }
      end
    else
      render :new 
    end
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    if @topic.update_attributes(topic_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to topic_path(@topic) }
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to strong-arm Rails like this. This hints at a poorly designed data structure. Why does editing a topic also edit a reply?

Comment: Because the content is in the reply. What structure you think would fit more appropriate for this?

Comment: Then why edit a topic if the content to be edited is in the reply? Edit the reply.

Comment: The title is related to the Topic, the content as a reply. I'm interested in hear how this could be done better.

Comment: Nested attributes are fine for `new` actions, but not for `edit` actions. I suggest you have separate edit actions/views for Topic and Reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a scoped association, the same way you are using `:owner_reply` but adding a scope to limit to the first record, you can also add a `order` to it if you need

```
class Topic
has_many :replies
has_many :first_replies, -> { first }, class_name: 'Reply'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
accepts_nested_attributes_for :first_replies
```

And in your view

```
= form_for @topic fo |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :first_replies
    = reply.text_area :content
```

Comment: I'm getting ' undefined method `except' for #<Reply:0x007f8463a58b80>' using your approach.

Comment: 'except'?? Where do you use this, I cannot see anywhere in the code you parsed?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class method on `Topic` that returns the first `Reply`:

```
class Topic
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :first_reply

  def self.first_reply
    self.replies.first
  end
  # ...
end
```

Then call the class method in `fields_for`.